# How to get a 'Show More' button on my NewForm.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, edit-form, newform

I know this 'Show More' button from the task form.
The important information are on top of my form. I want there to be a 'show more' button so the form looks very clear.

Any ideas? Thanks!